# Curl 100m possible ID#s

Tags: curl

I'm trying to curl and download a page for records that have an ID number assigned by the host. I'm using:

curl "http://hostname.com/dataport/RPQdata.asp?ID=[10000000-19445885]" -o "#1.html"

Rather than dl an html page for every record (I'm getting the site's error page for non-populated pages), and querying every number in that range which will likely take days or weeks, is there a way to find which ID numbers are being used (they only have about 125k actual IDs based on my knowledge of their industry) and then curl only those pages?

Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas or pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think, probably this isn't possible, unless you have some other interface into the system.

Comment: My thinking is this is why they did this... to prevent scraping. It's a gov site and the data should be released but, they like to be bullies about it. Bah.